# Custom List Not showing up

Tags: 2007, list, development, wss-3.0, custom-list

I created a list using a msdn tutorial as given in link below,

[MSDN Custom List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee871987%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

I followed each single step, and deployed the list, and I can see it deployed globally in Sharepoint Central Admin, + I can see it activated in "Site Feature" but when i go to "Site Actions" create a new list, I can't find it there, i used some other tutorials and I can see them custom lists,

one more thing is On my servers there isn't Visual Studio so is there any better way to create a custom list, and deploy it on servers, as atm I have to make changes to files generated by Visual Studio if i want to deploy this custom list feature.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a Category attribute to the ListTemplate element in ListDefinition.xml.

Category - Optional Text. Specifies the category with which to associate lists created through the list definition. Possible values include the following:

- Libraries
- Communications
- Tracking
- Custom Lists

Regarding how to develop for SharePoint. I'd say you should have a development environment with both SharePoint and VS installed. I'd not use the VS extensions for SharePoint, but prefer to use either WSPBuilder or STSDEV when developing for SharePoint 2007. For SharePoint 2010 you should use VS2010

Comment: thanks, it solved the problem I was looking into since friday, and we do use STSDAM on Servers.

Comment: + its a Sharepoint 2007